# SphereCastAll does not detect some collisions

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm casting SphereCastAll in direction of the red line and I sometimes have a strange issue that this cast misses some colliders like in the screen below. The green line shows SphereCastAll origin and closest hit with different rigidbody to not collides with own colliders. SphereCastAll radius is half of car width.

Sometimes SphereCastAll misses all colliders from car in front and hits the next car.

Rigidbody is moving by WheelColliders

[image: Image showing problem]

Comment: which car is casting?  the one on the left in the image?

Comment: include your casting code.  you may have chosen the wrong distances, or other simple problem.

Comment: Casting range is length of red line. Casting car is one without visible colliders.
The problem is that this occurs only from time to time. Most time it works good but when this happens cars crashed from each other

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [link](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/633966/spherecast-not-working-when-gameobject-are-at-the.html)

One interesting aspect of `Physics.SphereCast()` is that it occasionally fails if the sphere was already colliding with an object. Thus for `Physics.SphereCastAll()` it might not return the first (couple of) collisions if the sphere would already be colliding with them. Consider using `Physics.OverlapSphere()` to get the collisions you are missing or reducing the radius of the `SphereCast` to such a radius where the `SphereCast` cannot start inside of any other enemies / cars / what-have-you.